# Proper use of instance state save from fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment an `onCreateView` I do a background asyn call to fetch some data to display.
I save the object that is the result of the background call as a member variable of the fragment.
When I see the UI and the data all is ok and when I press the home button the app goes to background. When I reopen the app the data are in the UI inflated by my fragment.
So now I am not sure about the following:
1) Should I save my object in the `onSaveInstanceState`?
2) Where should I expect to restore it? In the bundle passed in the `onCreateView`?
3) When would the data be saved in my bundle? I mean how can I see that without saving it right now, I would lose the data from my UI?

Answer (score 1):

In your fragment constructor, add the following line:

```
 setRetainInstance(true);
```

> Control whether a fragment instance is retained across Activity
>   re-creation (such as from a configuration change).

Comment: So I can save in the bundle for the onSaveInstanceState but I can not use that?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your data (size).

Do you want to have a fragment on the back stack (with retained fragment you cannot)?

For "home button action" and non-retained Fragment implement Parcelable interface and use onSaveInstanceState() to save and onCreateView()/onCreate() to restore data from a Bundle.

Be aware for back button you will loose your data.

Comment: When I press home button and open the app the `onCreateView` is not being called

Comment: It works that way with setRetainInstance(true), onCreate() still will be called. And if you use retained fragment why do you want to save any data in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

> Also like an activity, you can retain the state of a fragment using a
>   Bundle, in case the activity's process is killed and you need to
>   restore the fragment state when the activity is recreated. You can
>   save the state during the fragment's onSaveInstanceState() callback
>   and restore it during either onCreate(), onCreateView(), or
>   onActivityCreated(). For more information about saving state, see the
>   Activities document.

It seems that your fragment works alright by fetching the data every time it's shown.

If you want to save its data to avoid the async fetching you can use `onSaveInstanceState`, which requires you to save your data using a `Bundle`.

Then in `onCreateView` check if `savedInstanceState` is `null` and if it is do the async fetch, otherwise recreate you data from the `savedInstanceState` `Bundle`.